# Wordpress Custom Themes > How to script Categories, Tags and Excerpt options to appear on "page" editor

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using custom WordPress categories for some probably unintended functions, I will admit (things like marking a post no/index just by adding it to my custom "no-index" category, etc). But it sucks that WordPress does not enable pages with all the little extras you get with posts.

For example, while the post editor gives you convenient access to Tags, Categories, and a Post excerpt field, pages get left out in the cold.

I'd like to know if its possible to add the These items to the Post editor via add_action() directive from a custom theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will add category and excerpt panels.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_page_excerpt_meta_box');
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_page_categories_meta_box');

function my_page_excerpt_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box('postexcerpt', __('Excerpt'), 'post_excerpt_meta_box', 'page', 'normal', 'core');
}

function my_page_categories_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box('categorydiv', __('Categories'), 'post_categories_meta_box', 'page', 'side', 'core');
}
```

Comment: Richard, you know your stuff. That was siiiiiiiick. Any ideas about Tags?

Comment: I don't know of any simple ways to add the tags panel. But, it looks like there are some existing plugins that will do it, e.g. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-tagger/